# Electrical connection between RP2040 and ESP-12F

Tags: pcb, wiring, esp8266, wifi, rp2040

I'm projecting a PCB board with a Raspberry RP2040 and the WiFi module Ai-Thinker ESP-12F (it is the only available from my PCB provider) following the [official documentation](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/hardware-design-with-rp2040.pdf), but I have some doubts about electrical connection between RP2040 and ESP-12F. I would like to use Raspberry RP2040 as main processor and ESP-12F only as Wi-Fi modem for data transmission (using Blynk IoT service). This is [my PCB schema](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/09dWVfvjn4_FL4miw3y4A31dw#Schematic_Raspberry_Wi-Fi_2023-01-06); this is the [Ai-Thinker datasheet](https://docs.ai-thinker.com/_media/esp8266/docs/esp-12f_product_specification_en.pdf).

[image: RP2040 Pinout]

This table is taken from the [official RP2040 datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/rp2040-datasheet.pdf). These are the first 10 pins of the RP2040. Can I connect TX from RP to RX of ESP and viceversa? How do I connect other pins in order to use ESP-12F as modem for data transmission over Wi-Fi?

Comment: There's no such thing as an ESP32-12F. Do you mean the ESP-12F (which is an ESP8266)? What do you want to accomplish by connecting these devices? You can certainly connect the serial ports of both devices (RX to TX and vice versa), but exactly what kind of data do you want to transfer between them?

Comment: Usually TX is the output and RX is the input, so you would need to drive ESP32's RX from RPi's TX, and vice versa. Connecting both TX outputs together won't work. If you're not sure, it's a good idea to give yourself a way to swap TX/RX on your board.

Comment: It depends what you want the boards to do and communicate between them. Obviously Tx and Rx are not enough as also ground connection is needed.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I want to give to Raspberry RP2040 Wi-Fi connectivity. So i want to use RP2040 as main processor and ESP-12F only for data transmission over Wi-Fi. I'm asking for the correct wiring diagram because I didn't find any example or documentation on Net.